# Movesense Showcase app does not show nearby sensors

Tags: android, movesense

Recently, we bought Movesense HR+ sensor and cloned and built the showcase app for android. The showcase app was successfully installed in the android phone. But it does not sense nearby Movesense sensors. We get an error called "Cannot connect to Bluetooth-error code 0". I have already given the location permission to the app. When I search the nearby Bluetooth devices using the same phone (not through the app) it shows the sensor. Moreover, the iOS showcase app works fine with the sensor and we could record ECG data using iOS app. However we are interested in developing the android app. Is there anyone who face similar situation? Any suggestions?

I tried contacting Movesense team but they haven't responded yet.

Comment: Have you tried with the latest showcase app from the bitbucket? There were some permission fixes for latest Android versions.